# system is out of gpu memory

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, memory-management

I am using Imac with following specification :

Processor: 4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

Memory : 32 GB 1867 MHz DDR3

Graphics : AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4 GB

[image]

I was trying to make stormy ocean from this video : youtu.be/oysCSbhXYBo?si=5TIzcs4TR7D80BN2. settings:
[image]

The system runs out of GPU after certain number of frames.
I can't understand why blender is not dumping previous frames data.
After restarting blender is working but I have to repeat it.
Is it because I am Rendering on Metal with both on.
Or is it because I am using Persistent data.Or is it because I am rendering in OpenEXR Format.
Please Help.

Comment: "a scene which I think is not complicated": Well, hard to tell without knowing the scene. 4 GB of RAM is not really a lot nowadays.. on the official site the minimum requirement is 2 GB, but recommended is 8 GB. "I can't understand why blender is not dumping previous frames data": I don't know either, but you say you use _Persistent Data_ - now this is exactly what it does, keeping render data in memory at the cost of extra memory usage. Ever tried it without?

Comment: Make sure you don't use 8k or 4k textures, this is the most likely culprit if your scene is "not complicated"

Comment: I am a beginner in blender. Afterwards I started using approximately 16 GB and I don't think I used any 4k or 8k texture but I used water simulation for ocean as I was trying to make stormy ocean from this video : youtu.be/oysCSbhXYBo?si=5TIzcs4TR7D80BN2. Thanks for the tip.
But my question was that is the problem due to using both AMD and Intel or anyone  is causing the problem or the problem is not related to it ?

Comment: Have you checked this aspect?  "Metal – Apple (macOS)
Metal is supported on Apple computers with Apple Silicon, AMD and Intel graphics cards. macOS 13.0 or newer is required to support all features and graphics cards.

Light Trees and Shadow Caustics are not supported when using an AMD graphics card with Metal." https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip but when  I enabled AMD ,the render time was roughly cut by half.